# YouTube Python Mortgage Calculator (Zero to Hero)

Tags: python, youtube

This is a code I got off the Zero to Hero with Python programming tutorial off YouTube to calculate a mortgage. I'm trying to understand why this code isn't giving me the same answers I'm getting using other payment calculators. I know there are other codes that will give me the correct answer, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this one...

```
# M = L[i(1+i)n]/[(1+i)n-1]


#Declare and initialize the variables
monthlyPayment = 0
loanAmount = 0
interestRate = 0
numberOfPayments = 0
loanDurationInYears = 0

#Ask the user for the values needed to calculate the monthly payments
strLoanAmount = input("How much money will you borrow? ")
strInterestRate = input("What is the interest rate on the loan? ")
strLoanDurationInYears = input("How many years will it take you to pay off the loan? " )

#Convert the strings into floating numbers so we can use them in the formula
loanDurationInYears = float(strLoanDurationInYears)
loanAmount = float(strLoanAmount)
interestRate = float(strInterestRate)

#Since payments are once per month, number of payments is number of years for the loan * 12
numberOfPayments = loanDurationInYears*12

#Calculate the monthly payment based on the formula
monthlyPayment = loanAmount * interestRate * (1+ interestRate) * numberOfPayments \
    / ((1 + interestRate) * numberOfPayments -1)

#provide the result to the user
print("Your monthly payment will be " + str(monthlyPayment))

#Extra credit
print("Your monthly payment will be $%.2f" % monthlyPayment)
```

Comment: You'll have to tell what's wrong with it. What is the result? What should it be? What are the input values?

Comment: I'm  pretty sure that isn't the correct formula, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula Notice that you don't multiply by n, but rather use n as an exponent. Also, for what it's worth, I would be very wary of a tutorial that tells you to "declare and initialize" Python variables like that. First, there is no such thing in Python, there is only variable assignment. While it can be useful to assign to a value before you do something with a variable, in this case, your code won't be affected, and you can delete those lines and get the exact same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a similar [post's][1] answer for the following code:

```
# M = L[i(1+i)n]/[(1+i)n-1]


#Declare and initialize the variables
monthlyPayment = 0.0
loanAmount = 0.0
interestRate = 0.0
numberOfPayments = 0.0
loanDurationInYears = 0.0

#Ask the user for the values needed to calculate the monthly payments
strLoanAmount = input("How much money will you borrow? ")
strInterestRate = input("What is the interest rate on the loan? ")
strLoanDurationInYears = input("How many years will it take you to pay off the loan? " )

#Convert the strings into floating numbers so we can use them in the formula
loanDurationInYears = float(strLoanDurationInYears)
loanAmount = float(strLoanAmount)
interestRate = float(strInterestRate)/100/12

#Since payments are once per month, number of payments is number of years for the loan * 12
numberOfPayments = float(loanDurationInYears)*12

#Calculate the monthly payment based on the formula
monthlyPayment = loanAmount * (interestRate * (1 + interestRate) ** numberOfPayments) / ((1 + interestRate) ** numberOfPayments - 1)

#provide the result to the user
print("Your monthly payment will be " + str(monthlyPayment))

#Extra credit
print("Your monthly payment will be $%.2f" % monthlyPayment)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804843/formula-for-calculating-interest-python
```

Comment: You should have flagged it as a repeat, then.

Comment: Yep, could have done that. Seemed as though giving the exact code was cleaner.