# Python Coding Issue for Loan Calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I am trying to create a loan calculator on a website and I am getting trouble in the coding of Python. The code is:

```
# user enter the cost of the loan, the interest rate, and
#the number of years for the loan
#Calculate monthly payments with the following formula
# M = L[i(1+i)n] / [(1+i)n-2]
# M = monthly payment
# L = Loan amount
# i = interest rate (for an interest rate of 5%, i = 0.05)
# n = number of payments
#________________________________________________________________________#
#Start of program
#Declare variables

monthlypayment = 0  
loanamount = 0
interestrate = 0
numberofpayments = 0  
loandurationinyears = 0
loanamount = raw_input("Lending Money ")
interestrate = raw_input("Interest Rates are? ")
loandurationinyears = raw_input("Time Duration in Years?")
#Convert the strings into floating numbers so we can use them in the formula
loandurationinyears = float(loandurationinyears)
loanamount = float(loanamount)
interestrate = float(interestrate)
#Since payments are once per month, number of payments is number of years for the loan
payments = loaninyears*12
#calculate the monthly payment based on the formula
payment = amount * interestrate * (7+ interestrate) * payments / ((1 + interestrate) * payments -1)
#Result to the program
print("Payment will be " + st(monthlypayment))
```

Can any experienced person help me to get the syntax or other logical errors in this coding?

Comment: `loaninyears` is not defined. You are multiplying it by 12.

Comment: `print("Payment will be " + st(monthlypayment))` I think `st` should be `str` here

Comment: amount should probably be loanamount and you never give monthlypayment a value other than 0

Answer (score 1):

You are reading variables that you have not previously declared.
Change *loaninyears* to *loandurationinyears* and *amount* to *loanamount*.

Additionally you have a typo in the last line, *st* should be *str*

Also some tips:

First, you can do stuff like:

```
input = float(raw_input("Give me some number"))
```

This way you can shorten the length of your program.

Also you might want to consider using a more readable variable naming, for example:

*loanInYears* or *loan_in_years*

Answer (score 0):

Following your formula in the comments closely, and using Python 2.7 , this runs, but the outcome isn't correct.

```
# user enter the cost of the loan, the interest rate, and
#the number of years for the loan
#Calculate monthly payments with the following formula
# M = monthly payment
# L = Loan amount
# i = interest rate (for an interest rate of 5%, i = 0.05)
# n = number of payments

L = input ('loan amount')
i = input ('interest rate')
n = input ('nr of payments')

M = L*(i*(1+i)*n) / ((1+i)*n-2)

print (M)
```

I think you should fix your formula first, apart from coding errors.
Specifically I miss the number 12 somewhere, since your interest is per year, but your payments are per month.

[EDIT]

Look at the answer of Joshy here:

[Formula for calculating interest Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804843/formula-for-calculating-interest-python)

and perhaps use a different video tutorial, since this one seems to get many folks in trouble.

Tip: ifyouhaveverylongvariablenames you_may_place_some_underscores_in_them