# calculating mortgage - python 3.8.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to calculate mortgage/loan and found a code on Stack Overflow (Dec.14 '18 at 17.13 Kravietz) but it doesn't work.

code:

```
import mortgage
m = mortgage.Mortgage(interest=0.0375, amount=350000, months=360)
mortgage.print_summary(m)
```

First I installed the module `mortgage`. First error:

```
AttributeError-module mortgage has no attribute Mortgage
```

Indeed, with `dir(mortgage)` I found out that there is no attribute `Mortgage`.
I changed `Mortgage` to `loan`, but no result.
I tried `from mortgage import loan`, no result.
I tried to add a print on the third line `print(mortgage.pr ...)`, no result.

errors:

```
NameError - name "interest" is not defined
TypeError - "module" is not callable
NameError - name "mortgage" is not defined
```

Comment: *First I installed the module* - how exactly did you install the module?

Comment: python3.8 -m pip install mortgage.  But it seems that there is more than one module using the name "mortgage" because the first installed did not work but the second from git.hub did.Confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the mortgage module to which Kravietz is referring in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29804843/14079207), it can be found at: https://github.com/jbmohler/mortgage

Comment: Because the code would work if he installed the github package, I strongly imagine OP has done ````pip install mortgage```` hence why they try to use ````Loan````

Comment: I had installed "mortgage" as follows
python3.8 -m pip install mortgage
Now I have downloaded the mortgage from Github and it works (mortgage.py)
The only problem I still have is how to change rate, amount,years,payoff months.
Running the mortgage.py gives fixed info but where to change it ?
And what is the difference between the mortgage i installed and the git.hub one ? a bit confusing same modulenames !

Comment: The interest, amount and months are passed in as arguments when you create an instance of the module class. I guess the fact that the names are the same is just due to unimaginative developers :)

Comment: I found it. The file mortgage.py was not in the same directory. Now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is something that could easily be done by creating a function that would calculate all the inputs such as interest, amount, months and it'd return the calculations
and so on. without the need to import any modules! I suggest looking for simple functions that calculate numbers and then edit it to fit your need! :)

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the question... For starters, the question is specifically about a `mortgage` module so offering not to use it is off the point. ANYWAY, if you want to offer another way, at least show it. Simply saying that the OP can implement it by himself is not really helpful...